# How do I remove the airplay from a video player for the ipad?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, video, avfoundation

So I have this player that I am using to video locally. I need to be able to mirror airplay the screen to a tv but every time I set airplay to mirror the player just sends the whole video to the screen instead of just mirroring.

https://github.com/NOUSguide/NGMoviePlayer

I contacted the developers about how to disable the airplay part of it. They told me to remove the airplay layer from the player. Can someone lead me into the right direction into getting this done?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable AirPlay, just set the `allowsAirPlay` property to false in your `MoviePlayerController` object.

You can access the mirrored screen by using this method :

```
UIScreen * screen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
```

before calling this method, ensure that the `screens` property has more than one object

Comment: The problem I had is the allowAirPlay doesn't work correctly. The video player still airplays